# How to resolve x if $(1 \cdot x) \cdot (1 \cdot x) \cdot (0.58 \cdot x) = 0.3333$

Tags: polynomials, roots, cubics

this should be an easy question, but I don't know the answer. I'm sorry I don't have a clue what to search for in the questions already posted.
So ... what is x if:

$x \cdot x \cdot (0.58 \cdot x) = 0.3333$

Well, I would like to know how to resolve x with different values for 0.58.

Thank you for your answer!
Matthew

Comment: $x=\sqrt[3]{0.3333/0.58}$?

Comment: more generally, for $a,b\in \Bbb R, a \neq 0$ we have $b=x\cdot x \cdot (a\cdot x)=x^3a$ and so $x^3=b/a$ implying $x = \sqrt[3]{b/a}$

Comment: But is the outcome to that not approximately 0.8707? Or am I wrong? Because 0.8707 does not fit the equation.

Comment: @mps How do you get $0.8707$? We have that
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{0.3333}{0.58}} \approx 0.8313854889. $$

Comment: I was taking the square root of the square root, which is wrong. The outcome is approximately 0.8314

Comment: @mps Yes, you have to take the cube root. It is also equivalent to raising to the power of one third, e.g.
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{0.3333}{0.58}} = \left(\frac{0.3333}{0.58}\right)^{1/3} \approx 0.8313854889. $$

Answer (score 2):

Generally:

$$(a\cdot x)(b\cdot x)(c\cdot x) = d$$

means

$$abc\cdot x^3 = d$$

hence

$$x = \sqrt[3]{\frac{d}{abc}}$$

Answer (score 1):

we have $$0.58x^3=0.3333$$
$$x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{0.3333}{0.58}}\approx 0.8314$$